# Crear servicio HttpClient para reutilizar

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api

¿Cómo debería crear mi servicio `HttpClient` para que sea instanciado una única vez en la aplicación para poder reutilizar dicha instancia durante toda la aplicación y evitar agotar los `sockets`?.

Todo esto dado que estoy consumiendo una WebApi.

Actualmente tengo mi servicio así:

```
public static HttpClient GenerateClient()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://0.0.0.0:0000/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(string.IsNullOrEmpty(token);

    return client;
}
```

Comment: Una opción que se me ocurre es la de crear tu  instancia como static para que sea "global" y puedas utilizarla en cualquier parte del código

Comment: Por cierto, tienes muchas preguntas y aún no has aceptado más que una sola. Si te han sido de utilidad considera marcarlas como respuesta correcto dando clic en `✓`.

Comment: @Flxtr es necesario colocar el ticket a todas las respuestas que se dejan sin importar que esa respuesta no me sirvió? Se supone que uno la marca si es que te resolvió la pregunta y en las que eh hecho solo unos pocos me han ayudado a resolver las dudas y esas están marcadas.

Answer (score 0):

Me temo que estás en una confusión, `HttpClient` solo te va a funcionar para hacer peticiones de tipo HTTP, es decir, petición/respuesta, a diferencia del socket que se mantiene una comunicación abierta.

Si lo que deseas es crear una petición HTTP, este sería un ejemplo muy básico:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var result = Client.GetAsync("http://miURL.com").Result;
    Console.WriteLine(result.StatusCode);
}
```

Si realmente deseas usar sockets, sugiero que revises la [documentación oficial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket(v=vs.110).aspx) y por acá te dejo otro [ejemplo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964694(v=vs.85).aspx) de cómo usarlos.

<sup>Abmos links están en inglés y corresponden a la MSDN.</sup>

Comment: En la documentacion de microsoft consumiendo api se indica que no se deveria manejar utilizando el using si no mas bien creando una unica instancia para llamar al servicio, de lo contrario se agotan los socket..

Comment: ¿me puedes proporcionar ese link de la documentación? El punto es que una cosa es hacer peticiones por medio de http y otra usar sockets

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client?#create-and-initialize-httpclient

Comment: En el mismo documento lo indica, no se recomienda usar HttpClient para trabajar con sockets, pero podrías usar `System.Net.Sockets`, justo esa clase está diseñada para trabajar con sockets.

Comment: No necesito usar `sockets` necesito usar `HttpClient` y en microsoft no dice que no se deben usar `Sockets` cito lo que dice: HttpClient está destinado a ser instanciado una vez y reutilizado a lo largo de la vida de una aplicación. Las siguientes condiciones pueden provocar errores SocketException : Crear una nueva instancia de HttpClient por solicitud puede agotar los sockets disponibles.

Comment: Entonces tienes que aclarar y saber qué es lo que necesitas, ya que por lo que veo no requieres más que hacer un simple petición HTTP y a partir de ahí ya vienen las implicaciones de qué tecnología usar. Ir directamente y revisar los riesgos de usar HTTP solo va a crear un juicio que realmente no sabes si aplique para tu escenario.

Comment: Lo que planeo hacer es lo que dice microsoft, cito: > HttpClient está destinado a ser instanciado una vez y reutilizado a lo largo de la vida de una aplicación

Comment: Eso es lo que necesito instanciarlo una unica vez para reutilizar el servicio en todas las solicitudes http que necesito hacer.

Comment: Sí, pero que sea una recomendación de la documentación oficial no asume que sea bajo todos los escenarios posibles, repito nuevamente, depende del objetivo de tu aplicación, depende del alcance de la aplicación. Una vez que sepas qué es lo que requieres podrás determinar una respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes implementar un patron **Singleton** para que siempre uses la misma instancia de tu **HttpClient**

```
static HttpClient _clientInstance;

public static HttpClient GenerateClient()
{
    if (_clientInstance == null) {
        _clientInstance = new HttpClient();
        _clientInstance.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://0.0.0.0:0000/");
        _clientInstance.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        _clientInstance.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        _clientInstance.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(string.IsNullOrEmpty(token);
    }
    return _clientInstance;
}
```

Cuando necesites un HttpClient siempre mandaras llamar tu función estática **GenerateClient**.

Para mas detalles del **Singleton** revista este link :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb972272.aspx